# How to Run Flutter Android Project Native Debug (android-> app module) with "--dart-define-file-from= config.json" config?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-run, dart-define

I can run my flutter project witth Android Studio with "--dart-define-file-from=" config and it works. But when I try to run same project's android module( for debugging native code I open android folder with Android Studio) it doesn't see my config file. I know I have to clarify it like editting run/debug configurations, but I don't know where to do it. Can you please provide me exact command or a solution?

My flutter command to run the code is :

flutter run --dart-define-from-file=base_config.json what should I do ?

I tried Compile options in Gradle-Android Compiler I wrote this command : -Pdart-define-from-file=base_config.json but it doesn't work.